# Show custom view before input entered on exposed form

Tags: 7, views

I have a page that displays a map with results based on an exposed search field, which is a required field.

I would like to display a custom view when the user visits the page and has not yet entered anything into the field - similar to [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/show-the-view-result-only-when-users-enter-a-value-for-the-exposed-fields) but another view rather than a custom result set. At the moment, the map shows all results when the page is first loaded, and I can't figure out how to change that behaviour.

I know that if I set the form to "Input required" I can enter custom text to be shown before the form is submitted, but I'd like to go a step further and be able to set a custom view to be shown much like the "No results behaviour" option.

Interestingly, with a "no results" view set, I can submit the form with an empty search field and my custom view will show. This is what I also need to be shown before anything has been submitted.

Is there a configuration where this is possible in views, or any way this can be achieved in code?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the [required_filter_input](https://www.drupal.org/project/required_filter_input) module is the way to go, as it requires one exposed filter to have a value before returning results, which triggers the custom "no results" view without any input by default.